# Prevent the rounding of double number

Tags: objective-c

In my code, I have a double number `2.555`. I used `%.2f` through NSLog to display it has `2.55` but the output is 2.56. It's rounding the number which I don't want it to! I know there is `ceil(double)` and `floor(double)` to be used, but they don't aid me here.

```
double div = a/b;
NSLog(@"DIV = %.f", div);
```

Comment: can you post your code here ?

Comment: The question is, why you don't want the number rounded but just truncated? For `2.555`, output `2.55` is invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing your code it is not possible to find the mistake. The below code will work according to your need.

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setRoundingMode:NSNumberFormatterRoundDown];
[numberFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
NSString *numberAsString = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:2.555]];
NSLog(@"%@",numberAsString);
[numberFormatter release];
```

you can refere this link for [NSNumberFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: oh thanks it did work. can't it be done in a simpler way? or should i always keep in mind the NSNumberFormatter?

Comment: The problem is a matter of how print format specifiers work in C. This ia a reasonable Objective-C solution.

Comment: It can't be done in a simpler way then this(According to my knowledge). You have to use NSNumberFormatter for this.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a simpler way to do this.
If I understand you correctly, you don't want to use floor() because you want to keep the contents of "div" unchanged. If this is correct then you can do the following.

NSLog( @"DIV = %.2f", trunc(div * 100) / 100 );
NSLog( @"DIV = %.2f", floor(div * 100) / 100 );

The above will hack off the decimals after the second, but only for display. the contents of "div" are unchanged.

Comment: This won't work. Floating point numbers doesn't work so easily.

Comment: It works most of the time, especially when the math doesn't push your number past the limits of the mantissa. I do agree however that you can only push a floating point number so far before the cracks start to show.